# How to render a specific data point marker on HightCharts Bell Curve?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
title: {
    text: null
},

legend: {
    enabled: false
},

xAxis: [{
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    visible: false
}, {
    title: {
        text: '5 Meter Sprint'
    },
    opposite: false,
    visible: true
}],

yAxis: [{
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    visible: false
}, {
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    opposite: true,
    visible: false
}],

series: [{
    name: null,
    type: 'bellcurve',
    xAxis: 1,
    yAxis: 1,
    intervals: 4,
    baseSeries: 1,
    enableMouseTracking: false,
}, {
    name: 'Data',
    data: data,
    visible: false,
}]
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0b24mwfs/40/

So I've been try to do a highly customized bell curve chart with HighCharts, right now I'm able to disable most of the stuff expect the xAxis and the bell curve itself, but How to render a point on the curve by passing it a specific value?

Update:
Seems like it called `marker` on highcharts, by default it is rendering all the markers along the curve, is there a way to let it render only one by specifying the value?

Comment: do you want to be able to hover over the bell curve and see all the data points? Or only show just 1 specific one?

Comment: @AndrewLohr Only shows 1 specific one (by passing a value) , it would be great if that point can have custom styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update generated points in `load` event: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g1qhj8bv/1/

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function () {
    this.series[0].points[10].update({
        marker: {
        enabled: true,
        fillColor: 'white',
        radius: 6,
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: 'red'
      }
    });
  }
}
```

},

The only problem is to find index of a point you need: `points[10]`. I think you can simply loop over them, until you find the needed one, then update.